# Comparing lists with text files

Tags: python, list, file, loops, nltk

I have the following list: `t = ['one', 'two', 'three']`

I want to read a file and add a point for every word that exists in the list. E.g. if `"one"` and `"two"` exists in "`CV.txt`", points = 2. If all of them exist, then points = 3.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize

t = ['one', 'two', 'three']
CV = open("cv.txt","r").read().lower()

points = 0

for words in t:
    if words in CV:
        #print(words)
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(words)
        print(words)
        li = len(words)
        print(li)
        points = li
        print(points)
```

Assuming `'CV.txt'` contains the words "`one`" and "`two`", and it is split by words (tokenized), 2 points should be added to the variable "`points`"

However, this code returns:

```
['one']
1
1
['two']
1
1
```

As you can see, the length is only 1, but it should be 2. I'm sure there's a more efficient way to to this with iterating loops or something rather than len.
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I can see you are not adding the length to total amount of points. You are just making it equal. Can that be the problem?

Comment: The length will equal the amount of points. For example, if 6 words exist, the length should be 6. 1 point for each word == 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to tokenize within loop, so may be easier way to do it would be as following:

- First tokenize the words in txt file
- Check each word that is common
  in `t`

And finally the points would be number of words in `common_words`.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize

t = ['one', 'two', 'three']
CV = open("untitled.txt","r").read().lower()

points = 0

words = nltk.word_tokenize(CV)
common_words = [word for word in words if word in t]
points = len(common_words)
```

Note: if you want to avoid duplicates then, you need set of common words as following in above code:

`common_words = set(word for word in words if word in t)`

Comment: Perfect. This code also eliminates characters that exist in the word. E.g. "telephone" contains "one". Thanks for that!

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.